# extracting output of system command using popen

Tags: c++, unix, posix-api

I am using following code for extracting output of system command .
I have not set path for "pic" in PATH variable. and i want to store 
output of command `"which pic"` and do not want to display it on console.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    FILE *fp;
  int status;
  char path[1035];
char *command = "which pic";


  /* Open the command for reading. */
  fp = popen(command, "r");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to run command\n" );
    exit(0);
  }

  /* Read the output a line at a time - output it. */
  while (fgets(path, sizeof(path)-1, fp) != NULL) {
   cout<<"<<<<<<<<<<,"<<endl;
    printf("%s", path);
  }

  /* close */
  pclose(fp);

  return 0;
}
```

but it displaying following output in console :

```
which: no pic in(/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin)
```

Comment: You haven't really formulated a question, but one comment is that most likely, this output of `which` goes to standard error instead of standard output. You'll want to capture both.

Comment: cout<< and printf  in same code!

Comment: @Angew You have solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Run `"which pic 2>&1"` as your command. You want to capture all output from `which`, including its errors (which are sent to stderr).